# Terminology for a bijection from a set to itself

Tags: co.combinatorics, terminology, partitions, bijective-combinatorics

A current project uses bijections from a set to itself.  (The set is the integer compositions of $n$, i.e., "ordered partitions of $n$," but that doesn't seem pertinent to the question.)  Is there a more specific name for such maps?  These do not have order two, so involution is not correct.  There is not an algebraic structure being considered, so automorphism doesn't sound right...

Comment: "permutation"? I need to add length.

Comment: @VilleSalo  Hmm, maybe.  I think of permutations in a very specific algebraic combinatorics sense, e.g., pattern avoiding permutations.

Comment: I agree with "permutation".

Comment: An example of a post on this site where *permutation* is used for an infinite set: [Cardinality of the permutations of an infinite set](https://mathoverflow.net/q/27785). And a related question on [math.se]: [Is it correct to say that every bijection of a set onto itself is a permutation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3205279)

Comment: The word is "permutation". Mathematicians have been reluctant for some time to accept the existence of infinite sets, and some of them are still reluctant to use the terminology "permutations" in the context of infinite sets.

Comment: Historical note: the 1st appearance of permutations of infinite sets (explicitly) is maybe [Vitali's 1915 note](https://www.normalesup.org/~cornulier/Vitali_1915.pdf), where is was called (in Italian) "substitution" — "substitution" was indeed common for permutations of finite sets, notably in C. Jordan's famous *Traité des substitutions*. Vitali wrote (my translation) *"We'll call* ***substitution*** *the transition from the permutation $1,2,3\dots,N,N+1,\dots$ to an arbitrary permutation"*. Of course "substitution" is now an obsolete terminology and I've never seen it in any modern text.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Permutation is the term I would use (indeed, when I teach, I define a "permutation" of a set $X$ as a bijection from $X$ to itself).

Comment: Thanks for all the responses.  As an aside, I found an [MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46201/does-every-permutation-autojection-on-a-magma-binary-algebra-induce-another) that used "autojection" to the consternation of many.

Comment: @BrianHopkins, I originally read [that](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/437510/terminology-for-a-bijection-from-a-set-to-itself/437511#comment1127813_437512) as "autobijection", which is literally the first thing that occurred to me (before reading all the comments and answers proposing "permutation", which is of course the right answer), and which seems to me to be technically correct, if jarring.  But, however much or litte traction I can imagine "autobijection" getting, "autojection" (trying to follow the "homomorphism" → "automorphism" model, I guess) would surely get less.

Comment: And furthermore, $X!$ is a standard notaton for the set of permutations of a set $X$, meaning the set of bijections of $X$ with itself.

Comment: For the group of permutations of $X$, I have seldom seen the notation "$X!$" (choices of notation are sensitive to math communities, so I'm not saying it doesn't exist. Actually the use of "!" is confusing when the sentence/phrase is ending, but this is already a problem with the factorial notation $n!$. Calling it "set of permutations" rather than "group of permutations" would be strange in group theory :) but may be natural in combinatorics. The notation I've mostly seen: $S(X)$, $S_X$ $\mathrm{Sym}(X)$, $\mathrm{Sym}_X$, $\mathfrak{S}(X)$, $\mathfrak{S}_X$ ($\mathfrak{S}$ is \mathfrak{S}).

Comment: I concur with YCor, and would add that I've also seen $\Sigma_X$ and $\Sigma(X)$.

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia has this nice graphics about about different mappings:

[image]

I believe you looking for either
[Automorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automorphism) or
[Endomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endomorphism#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20an%20endomorphism%20is,homomorphism%20f%3A%20G%20%E2%86%92%20G.).

Comment: Thanks, Max.  My discomfort with -morphism is that there's no underlying structure being preserved.

Comment: These are literally automorphisms in the category Set.

Comment: @VilleSalo So in a combinatorics article (where the word category never arises), would you call these maps permutations or automorphisms?

Comment: I would call them permutations, definitely.